# Soft keybord Del key doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am using edit text for my application for which soft keyboard is used.

I'm using a text watcher, as suggested in the posts on how to detect soft keyboard key press events, but I'm unable to delete the data which I've entered in the edit text. This means that the del key is not called in the text watcher.

I have set the ime options to "action done", but it's still not working, here's what I've done to invoke the soft keyboard:

```
((CustomEditText)v).setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) BookModel.getInstance()
                            .get_mActivity()
                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(),
                              InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
                              InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```